# At what reputation can an SO user view deleted posts and comments?

Tags: discussion

I have tried checking privileges but i've not found anything like `View Deleted Posts`. So thats why I'm asking, At what reputation can a Stack Overflow user view deleted posts and comments

Or is it reserved only for moderators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At 10,000 you can see deleted posts.

You can see that on the [Stack Overflow Privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Deleted comments are Moderator only (and a recent change at that).

Answer (score 5):

At [10,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) users can see deleted posts. But only moderators can see deleted comments.